# How to replace .png with a constant for another image within an image_tag in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, png, frontend

I am trying to replace an image that is a .png with another image; this other image is not a .png, but rather there is a class for it.

Here is the original code:

```
<%= log.has_attachments? ?
    image_tag('paper.png', :fingerprinting => false, :title => I18n.t('views.global.attachments')) :
    image_tag('blank_16_square.png', :fingerprinting => false) %>
```

I tried to replace the one line with the .png with the class like so:

```
image_tag( {:class => 'fa fa-paper'}, :fingerprinting => false, :title => I18n.t('views.global.attachments')) :
```

The image I want to implement is in a file written like this:

```
const ICON_CLASSES = {
    paperclip: 'fa fa-paper',
    starred: 'fa fa-star',
    warning: 'fa fa-warning',
};
```

My attempt to change the code results in a broken image. Is it possible to add the image with its class? How would I do this?

Comment: what you try to achieve?

Comment: I am replacing one image that is a .png with another image. That other image is not a .png. It is written in another files under `const ICON_CLASSES = {` I'm going to update the question

Comment: you can solve this via `jquery`,first select element which you want to replace image and remove image from that and add othere image

Comment: `image_tag( {:class => 'fa fa-paper'}, :fingerprinting => false, :title => I18n.t('views.global.attachments')) :
` you can use image_tag without image it will throw a broken image